# How to set a collection size in a symfony2 form

Tags: symfony

What i want to do is creating 4 form ResponseType inside the form QuestionType() , is it possible to fix the size of the colllection of responses ?

my code for QuestionType :

```
$builder->add('responses', 'collection', array(

        'type'         => new ResponseType(),

        'allow_add'    => true,

        'allow_delete' => true,



      ))
        ;
```

Comment: if by "to fix the size" you mean allow at maximum 4 child entities, then you probably have to change javascript to hide "add" button after adding 4 enitties and also add check in controller, or to FormEvent that would accept only 4 child entities

Comment: Do you want exactly 4 or up to 4? Do you need to validate this value after submitting the form?

Comment: i want exactly 4 form , yes i need to persist the 4 entites

Comment: Could you please expand your question and add the relevant part of the entities (Question, Response)?

Answer (score 0):

I know that question is old. But I just got on it.

You have to use the [Count](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html) constraint on your collection field.

So in your `QuestionType`

```
/**
* @Assert\Count(max=4, maxMessage="You can have max {{ limit }} reponses")
*/

private $responses;
```